# Splash screen jnlp not working

Tags: java, web-applications, java-web-start, splash-screen, jnlp

I am trying to get the splash screen working when i am calling a .jar thru JWS 
Below are the details of the jnlp file. Other features are working as expected.
I have placed the **pic.gif** file in ROOT folder of Apache tomact

**JaNeLA Report - version 11.05.17**

Report for http://localhost:8080/WithoutManifest.jnlp

1.XML encoding not known, but declared as UTF-8

2. Optimize this application for off-line use by adding the  flag.
3. Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'WithoutManifest.jar'.
4. The resource download at WithoutManifest.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.

5.The resource download at WithoutManifest.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.

6. It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the WithoutManifest.jar resource.
7. Lazy downloads might not work as expected for WithoutManifest.jar unless the download 'part' is specified.
8. Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'pic.gif'.
   Icon loading & use can be optimized by specifying the width and height for pic.gif
9. The HREF of 'http://localhost:8080/' could be optimized to ''.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/" href="WithoutManifest.jnlp">
>
>      <information>
>           <title>TITLE</title>
>           <vendor>Pallab</vendor>
>           <homepage href="http://localhost:8080/" />
>          <icon kind="splash" href="pic.gif"/>
>      </information>
>
>      <security>
>           <all-permissions/>
>      </security>
>
>      <resources>
>           <j2se version="1.6+" />
>           <jar href="WithoutManifest.jar" />
>      </resources>
>
>      <application-desc main-class="WithoutManifest" />
> </jnlp>
> ```

I am only seeing below two Pop-up before my actual application.

[image: Image 1]

Also how can i change the below values selected in RED, i am not providing those anywhere in .jnlp file

[image: Image 2]

Apache version -8.0.23
Java version - 1.8.0_40-b26

Comment: *"Also how can i change the below values.."* Wait.. what was the **first** question?  I missed it..  Note also, that each question on SO should be in a separate question thread.  I could answer the one question I see, but will wait for clarification as to which you want answered in this thread.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am expecting the first image (having java icon) should change as per splash screen,(its my understanding), is my 1st question. 2nd question is how to change the "Name" and "publisher" fields

Comment: And.. which **one** do you want answered in this thread?  As an aside, the first 'question' still is not a question!  Here are examples of actual questions *"How do I get the splash screen to appear?"*  or *"Why is the splash screen **not** appearing?"*

Comment: ok,  pls help on the 1st one, How do I get the splash screen to appear? in my case, will post 2nd question in new thread

Comment: Any help on this ? still i am getting same issue.

Answer (score 2):

The splash screen will not appear on first launch.  The priority for the first launch is to get the classes downloaded and cached, and the app. on-screen.

Comment: it still don't appear after 1st launch, i tired it multiple times, no luck

Comment: That kinda stinks that it doesn't work on first launch, but this matches with what I've seen. If it still doesn't work, make sure the URL you specified in the jnlp actually works in a browser first - sometimes it's easy to make a silly mistake and have the file in the wrong location, etc.