# Java Web Start Screen not showing correct values

Tags: java, web, java-web-start, splash-screen, jnlp

I am asking the 2nd question in this post as accidentally i asked two in one thread. Link to original post ->[POST 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31317806/splash-screen-jnlp-not-working).
I am trying to run JWS and not getting the desired values in pop up screen.

**How can i change the selected portion in red in below image, as i am not providing those in my JNLP file?**

[image: pop up screen]

Below are details.

1. **JNLP file :**

   ```
    <information>
         <title>TITLE</title>
         <vendor>Pallab</vendor>
         <homepage href="http://localhost:8080/" />
        <icon kind="splash" href="pic.gif"/>
    </information>

    <security>
         <all-permissions/>
    </security>

    <resources>
         <j2se version="1.6+" />
         <jar href="WithoutManifest.jar" />
    </resources>

    <application-desc main-class="WithoutManifest" />
   ```
2. **JaNeLA Report - version 11.05.17 :**

Report for http://localhost:8080/WithoutManifest.jnlp

1.XML encoding not known, but declared as UTF-8

Optimize this application for off-line use by adding the flag.

Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'WithoutManifest.jar'.

The resource download at WithoutManifest.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.

5.The resource download at WithoutManifest.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.

It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by specifying download='lazy' for the WithoutManifest.jar resource.

Lazy downloads might not work as expected for WithoutManifest.jar unless the download 'part' is specified.

Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'pic.gif'. Icon loading & use can be optimized by specifying the width and height for pic.gif

The HREF of 'http://localhost:8080/' could be optimized to ''.

Apache version -8.0.23 Java version - 1.8.0_40-b26

Comment: It's been a while since I last worked with JNLP, but aren't those two values extracted from the code signing certificate?

Comment: I used the below commands, may be "name" is taken from alias,
how to change the "publisher"?

keytool -genkey -keystore WithoutManifest -alias WithoutManifest

jarsigner -keystore WithoutManifest WithoutManifest.jar WithoutManifest

Comment: This is the common behavior for code that is not trusted.  The JNLP declares `all-permissions` which should (in a late model JRE) indicate the code **has already been** signed using a code signing certificate issued by a Certification Authority (and is, therefore, trusted).  OTOH I note though, that the JNLP declares 1.6+.  In 1.6 and some early 1.7 JREs, it was possible to run code that had been 'self signed'.  Sun decided that since 'self signed' code by be forged (E.G. I could pretend to be you), showing a publisher was ..detrimental.

Comment: you mean to say if the certificate is signed by CA, it will show up in publisher ?